# Race condition in Airflow dynamic DAG

Tags: python-3.x, airflow, airflow-scheduler

I have an Airflow DAG that looks like this (Airflow 1.10.15):

[image: Airflow DAG]

Cubes type:

- lvl0_parser: Kuberenetes Operator
- get_rawdata_tables: Python Operator
- end_of_data_collectors: Dummy Operator
- all the rest (blue cubes) are also Python Operators.

I'm facing an issue that happens in rare use cases (which I still couldn't figure out), which is that the "end_of_data_collectors" cubes (DummyOperator) starts before the previous cubes finished.
An important detail is that cube "get_rawdata_tables" creates a JSON file that describes the next cubes that should be opened (the cubes between "get_rawdata_tables" and "end_of_data_collectors") and then we open them on runtime - the DAG is not static (which I know is not officially supported or recommended, but it works - most of the time). All trigger rules are set to the default "on success"

I suspect that the problem is related to long parsing time of the DAG in case of a lot of dynamic cubes, but I'm not sure.

My questions are:

1. In case I configure Airflow scheduler to run every minute, is it also running when each cube finishes to validate the next dependency? or just every minute regardless of what's happening in the DAG.
2. I've been working like this for 3.5 years and it happend to me on few use cases only after changing "end_of_data_collectors" to be DummyOperator (it was Kubernetes Operator before) - Do you think it could be a reason? something in this Operator behaves differently so it can explain this issue?
3. Do you think my theory about race condition between the scheduler and the DAG parsing make sense?

Thanks

Comment: I have no aswer to your question because Airflow 1.10.* is end of life for almost a year now and I think no-one really looks at analysing and understanding what happened there as there will be no more even critical security fixes, so it makes no sense to spend any time on it.

Airflow 2 parsing and scheduling has been vastrly improved and significantly rewritten nearly from scratch precisely to adrres similar racing conditions and long-time generation of DAGs, so I heartily recommend to migrare rather than spending your time (and tapping into other's time).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could figure it out, looks like Airflow scheduler ignores the Dummy Operator cube ("end_of_data_collectors"), skips it and marks it as "finish successfully" and then continues.

I also found an evidence to this behavior in Airflow code:

[image]

Looks like it wasn't a good idea to use Dummy Operator in dynamic use cases.